# Animate a UINavigationBar's barTintColor

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

The app I'm working on changes the `barTintColor` of its navigation bar when pushing new view controllers. Right now we set that colour in the destination view controller's `viewWillAppear:`method, but we have a few issues with that.

With the way we're doing this right now, the navigation bar's colour changes abruptly, while the rest of the bar content animates as usual. What I'd like is for the bar to fade between the source and destination colour. Is there any way to achieve this with public Cocoa Touch APIs?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can add extra animations that match the timing and animation curve of the view controller transition using [UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

A view controller's `transitionCoordinator` will be set *after* a view controller's animation has started (so in `viewWillAppear` of the presented view controller). Add any extra animations using `animateAlongsideTransition:completion:` on the transition coordinator.

An example:

```
[[self transitionCoordinator] animateAlongsideTransition:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
} completion:nil];
```

Comment: This doesn't work on iOS 9 and 10. It just switches the color directly. Pretty weird regarding the fact that it works in prepareForSegue

Comment: This works for me in iOS10 during push but not pop (for pop, it switches the color directly after the pop animation)

Comment: @Happiehappie Yeah, but I had to do it a hacky way to get the result I wanted. Posted in case it's useful to anyone. http://stackoverflow.com/a/42405212/1575848

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simpler fix. The issue with `barTintColor` not animating correctly on pop occurs when you try to set the navigation bar appearance in `viewWillDisappear`. The fix is to set it in `willMove(toParentViewController:)` instead.

The code below will produce a smooth fading transition during both push and pop, and regardless of whether it is initiated by a gesture or button tap. Tested on iOS 10 and 11.

This also works for animating `barStyle`.

```swift
import UIKit

class RedViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.title = "Red"
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .red
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .white
    }

    override func willMove(toParentViewController parent: UIViewController?) {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .white
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = nil
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be the right answer. Simple and elegant!

Answer (score 1):

To get a smooth animation during both push and pop, I had to make the navigation bar transparent and animate my own background color view behind it.

#### Here's my UINavigationController subclass that handles it:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class ColorTransitionNavigationController: UINavigationController {

    var navigationBarBackgroundView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Put a background view behind the navigation bar
        navigationBarBackgroundView = UIView()
        view.insertSubview(navigationBarBackgroundView, belowSubview: navigationBar)

        // Make the navigation bar transparent
        navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
        navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)

        // Size the colored background to match the navigation bar
        navigationBarBackgroundView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        navigationBarBackgroundView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        navigationBarBackgroundView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        navigationBarBackgroundView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true

        // I used a hard-coded 64 instead of constraining to the height of the navigation bar because
        // when calling navigationController.setNavigationBarHidden(true), the height of the navigation bar becomes 0
        navigationBarBackgroundView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 64.0).isActive = true

    }

    func setBarTintColor(color: UIColor, animated: Bool, transitionCoordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator?) {
        guard let transitionCoordinator = transitionCoordinator, animated else {
            navigationBarBackgroundView.backgroundColor = color
            return
        }

        transitionCoordinator.animateAlongsideTransition(in: view, animation: { [weak self] (context) in

            let transition = CATransition()
            transition.duration = context.transitionDuration
            transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
            self?.navigationBarBackgroundView.layer.add(transition, forKey: nil)
            self?.navigationBarBackgroundView.backgroundColor = color

        }, completion:nil)
    }
}
```

#### Usage:

If you want a UIViewController to animate the navigation bar color when it appears, override `viewWillAppear` and call `setBarTintColor`.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        guard let navigationController = navigationController as? ColorTransitionNavigationController else { return }
        navigationController.setBarTintColor(color: UIColor.green, animated: animated, transitionCoordinator: transitionCoordinator)
    }
```

Comment: Did you get this to work with the title color aswell?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't recall, I don't think I tried changing the title color in my case.