# Animate barTintColor on push segue

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uinavigationbar, bartintcolor

I would like to animate `barTintColor` property when **transitioning from one `view controller` to another**.

I have tried with following solution:

```
[[self transitionCoordinator] animateAlongsideTransition:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
} completion:nil];
```

which animates `barTintColor` as it should but my **navigation bar** should be translucent. To fix this problem I tried to set it to `translucent = YES` in completion block of `trasitionCoordinator`animation. Like this:

```
completion:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
}
```

but that causes slight jump in `barTintColor` value of **navigation bar** after the animation is completed. This is expected since translucent and opaque colors are different.

Similar questions:
[[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19272698/ios-7-uinavigationcontroller-navbar-per-controller-color-animation)
[[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593760/animate-a-uinavigationbars-bartintcolor)

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**:

I forgot to add that some strange scale animation appears from top left corner in **navigation bar** if I remove the `self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;` line from animation block. So that's not the solution either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question while still being open for other suggestions/solutions.

My solution which I think is quite a "clean one" is to make an **alpha blended color from original color with appropriate blend color**. So let's say we have a white background behind a **navigation bar** and we would like to animate current **navigation bar** `barTintColor` to green color. In this case we have to blend original green color with white color and appropriate alpha value.

After some playing with values I found out that alpha **0.16** works best for iOS 7 cases (I haven't tested it on other OS versions).

Animation block written in my original **question** implemented with my solution looks like this:

*Pay attention to **ALPHA BLENDED ORIGINAL COLOR** and **ORIGINAL COLOR***

```
[[self transitionCoordinator] animateAlongsideTransition:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = <ALPHA BLENDED ORIGINAL COLOR>;
} completion:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = <ORIGINAL COLOR>;
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
}];
```

**Equation for alpha blending**:

```
CGFloat bR = ((bcR - cR) * alpha + cR);
CGFloat bG = ((bcG - cG) * alpha + cG);
CGFloat bB = ((bcB - cB) * alpha + cB);
```

**values being**:

```
cR, cG, cB     = original color R,G,B components
bcR, bcG, bcB  = blending color R,G,B components
alpha          = alpha value to blend with
================================================
bR, bG, bB     = blended R,G,B components
```

Anyone who likes this solution is welcome to use a `UIColor`'s category for alpha blending I wrote for this case. You can find it [here](https://github.com/damirstuhec/UIColor-AlphaBlend).

Thanks.

Comment: It makes no difference for me. iOS9/10 and there is simply no animation at all, it just changes the color in one step. Does your solution still work or do you have an app online where I can check if it does?